# How to prove that EPR outcomes have equal probability no matter the basis?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, textbook-and-exercises, non-locality, state-preparation

Recently in class, we learned about the EPR state. I know that no matter what basis the first qubit is measured in, the two outcomes have an equal probability. However, how does one prove this? I somewhat understand what is happening and why, but if you know where a through proof of this might be that would be amazing.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\rho_{AB}$ be a quantum state shared between two parties, Alice and Bob. Suppose Alice performs a POVM measurement $\{M_i\}_i$ on her half of the state. Then the probability that Alice obtains outcome $i$ is given by the Born rule as
$$
p(i) = \mathrm{Tr}[\rho_{AB}(M_i \otimes I)].
$$
But whenever we have the trace of a multipartite operator we can always perform a partial trace first, i.e., $\mathrm{Tr}[X] = \mathrm{Tr}[\mathrm{Tr}_B[X]]$. So in this case
$$
p(i) = \mathrm{Tr}[\mathrm{Tr}_B[\rho_{AB}(M_i \otimes I)]] = \mathrm{Tr}[\rho_{A} M_i]
$$
where $\rho_A = \mathrm{Tr}_B[\rho_{AB}]$. For the EPR states, if you calculate $\rho_A$ (you should verify this) you'll find it is equal to $I/2$ (the maximally mixed state). Thus for the EPR states
$$
p(i) = \mathrm{Tr}[I/2 M_i] = \frac12 \mathrm{Tr}[M_i].
$$
Now if $M_i$ is a rank one qubit projector (which I'm assuming is what you meant by a measurement) then $\mathrm{Tr}[M_i] = 1$.

Answer (score 3):

The local state (described by density matrix) of each qubit in EPR state is
\begin{equation}
\rho=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
It does not depend on basis, so both outcomes have 50% probabilities in every measurement basis.

Proving directly the expression for qubit's local state is a little long.

The EPR state is pure 2-qubit state
$$
|\Psi\rangle_{EPR}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle|0\rangle+|1\rangle|1\rangle)
$$
or in the standard basis
$$
|\Psi\rangle_{EPR}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}{1\\0\\0\\1}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The 2-qubit density matrix is
$$
\rho_{AB}=|\Psi\rangle_{EPR} \langle \Psi|_{EPR}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\1
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and the local state of say qubit $A$ is given by the partial trace over qubit $B$
$$
\rho_A=tr_B[\rho_{AB}]=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The same expression is obtained for qubit $B$